# How do we write this in javascript $(this).parent('p')

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

How do i write this selector in plain javascript

```
$(this).parent('p')
```

Comment: Which browsers are you trying to have this work on?  You may want to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors

Comment: @james I'm looking for cross browser solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the jQuery `.parent(selector)` function only checks the immediate parent, you can create a function like this:

```
function getParent(o, tag) {
    if (o.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == tag.toLowerCase()) {
        return(o.parentNode);
    } else {
        return(null);
    }
}
```

Then, you can just call this:

```
getParent(this, 'p');
```

---

Or, if you want it to return an array similar to how jQuery does it, you would use this:

```
function getParent(o, tag) {
    var results = [];
    if (o.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == tag.toLowerCase()) {
        results.push(o.parentNode);
    }
    return(results);
}
```

Then, you can just call this (and get an array back):

```
getParent(this, 'p');
```

---

If you wanted the equivalent of the jQuery `.parents(selector)` function that returns all ancestors that match a tag type, you would use this:

```
function getParents(o, tag) {
    var results = [];
    while ((o = o.parentNode) && o.tagName) {
        if (o.tagName.toLowerCase() == tag.toLowerCase()) {
            results.push(o);
        }
    }
    return(results);
}
```

And, you would call it like this:

```
getParents(this, 'p');
```

Comment: Throws an error if there is no parent with a matching tag name. Need to do `if (o.tagName && o.tagName.toLowerCase() ... )`

Comment: Clear explanation. Thanks for all the variations.

Answer (score 3):

```
var p = this.parentNode;
var result = []; // empty
if (/p/i.test(p.nodeName))
   result = [p]; // return in jQuery array format (or not)
```

Comment: How does this compare to jquery's `$(this).parent('p')` performance wise.

Comment: Roughly 2200msec for jQuery vs 50msec for the raw according to [this test case fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5D8X/).

Comment: Your kidding - jQuery takes 2.2 seconds to check the parentNode?

Comment: @RobG that confused me too, but if you look at the fiddle it does it in a loop with 100000 or so iterations each

Answer (score 1):

This function should do it:

```
 var getAncestorOfTagType = function (e, type) {
    while (e.parentNode && e.tagName != type)
      e = e.parentNode;
    return e; 
 }
```

then

```
var p = getAncestorOfTagType(this, 'P')
```

Comment: OP asked for `.parent`, not `.parents`

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right, although that seems so trivial and non-useful it makes me wonder if that is what they are after.  Mine is "get the containing paragraph element, or null if there isn't one" while yours is "get the direct containing element, if it is a paragraph element, and stick it into a one member array.  Or return an empty array if parent is not a paragraph".

Comment: Yes i was asking for parent. +1 for showing how parents work.

Comment: This answer made my day. Note that it will return you the first result found only, not a collection. Such as `.parents('form:first')` would do.

Answer (score 1):

```
( node = theObject.parentNode ).tagName == "P" ? node : false;
```

Comment: The element doesn't have an id reference. Either way +1 for showing this alternative.